Guidance on placement of conanfile.py
How can I decide if I should place the conanfile.py in a subfolder like recipes/foo/conanfile.py, or if I should put it into the root folder of the repository?
What I have seen so far, is that if I have the conanfile.py in a separate folder, then I need to resort to custom configurations like explicitly setting the src_folder in cmake_layout`:
cmake_layout(self, src_folder="../../src")
or having to set the root explicitly:
self.folders.root = "../.."
Is that a good practice or does that indicate a problem in my conanfile?

The canonical layout is having the conanfile.py in the root of the repo, and that greatly simplify many things, the developer flows (that don't need to figure out where is the conanfile to install dependencies), to the recipe definition of layout. In general the benefits of having the conanfile.py in the root outperforms the inconvenience of putting the conanfile in a subfolder.
